# How to get transaction Id of a transaction inside the transaction processor function?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I would like to return the transaction id after successful submitting a transaction in Hyperledger composer. How do I get the transaction id inside the transaction processor function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in Playground - using Historian? (Click 'All Transactions' on the left under 'Test' - it will show the transaction ID)

Or you can get the trxn IDs using the APIs getHistorian in the client APIs.

Or by get them by transaction class (eg PaySeller transaction class)

Using the Composer client APIs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/jsdoc/module-composer-client.BusinessNetworkConnection.html#getTransactionRegistry__anchor for the transaction class in question. Each transaction will have a transaction ID.

Comment: Thank for the link sir, but would like to know how I can store all those Id's from the programming end there by I should be able to see all the Id's in the output console.

Comment: OK, going back to your original question - take this sample network script -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js you would get the transaction ID (as you're in a transaction) using `console.log("Transaction id is " + trade.transactionId);`

Comment: Thank you Paul O'Mahony, it worked fine for me. I have two functions one is for createProduct and orderProduct I have id's for both of these now I want to query all the details of that product by using this Id. How can I query those details. Please suggest some references.  Thank you.

Comment: you can create a query on the transaction class(es) - then call it/each from a TP function (or from your client as you see fit) - with an array of trxn IDs provided to that query transaction, you can (when you found the id in question), use the relationship to the ProductId (that was stored as a relationship on the transaction) to source the Product (or Order as the case may be) Details you want, in your `for` loop and process accordingly etc

Comment: //This is in one function
  product.orderIds = [createProduct.product.productId];
  product.orderPersons = [createProduct.product.productManufacturer];

Comment: //In other function
   var Ids = productObject[n].orderIds;
                  Ids.push(order.orderId);
                   var transactions=productObject[n].transactionIds;
                  var persons= productObject[n].orderPersons;
                  persons.push(order.orderPerson);
                   transactions.push(orderProduct.transactionId);
                    var x  = transactions.toString();
                  if(productObject[n].transactionIds == x){
                     console.log(Ids, persons);
                     }

Comment: I have removed all the console logs as it is not letting me to send. I am getting output in Array format. It's working fine. But would like to know one more thing can we query all the details from DB or something else.

Comment: I mean like can we query that from DB by giving transaction Id?

Comment: yes, you can query by giving a trxn ID - to query the transaction class

Comment: I just want to give a transactionId, thereby want to retrive all the details. Can u suggest some ways or links useful for this?